# Is there a simple way to get all discontinuities of a function in a certain domain with sympy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, sympy

Given an expression in sympy, is there a way to find all discontinuities in a given interval?  For instance, given 1/(x^2-1) from -2 to 2, it would return -1 and 1.  It doesn't have to be symbolic.  A numerical solution may actually work better for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `singularities` module for this.

```
In [ ]: from sympy import *  
In [ ]: init_printing()
In [ ]: x = symbols('x')
In [ ]: singularities(1/(x**2 - 1), x)
Out[ ]: (-1, 1) # A tuple of SymPy objects
```

Reference: http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/calculus/index.html#sympy.calculus.singularities.singularities

Comment: This looks promising... It seems to be implemented simply as `tuple(sorted(solve(simplify(1/expr), sym)))` which is essentially the same method I used in my answer. However, it only works with a very restricted class of functions (e.g. it doesn't handle any trigonometric functions like my `expr2` example), so it looks to be very much a work in progress.

Comment: @ajcr Yeah. Like you said, its under development.
It currently works for univariate, real rational functions.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I don't think that there's any specific method in SymPy to do this;</strike> it might be very difficult to do in full generality (i.e. for any possible function, in any number of variables, including those with [infinite discontinuities](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfiniteDiscontinuity.html)).

If you're working with relatively simple expressions in one real variable, such as the example in your question, then one approach could be to compute the expression as a ratio of two expressions and then solve the denominator expression.

```
>>> expr
1/(x**2 - 1)
>>> n, d = expr.as_numer_denom()
>>> sympy.solve(d)
[-1, 1]
```

Another small example:

```
>>> expr2 = 1/(sympy.sin(x)) + 4/(x**2 - 3)
>>> expr2
1/sin(x) + 4/(x - 3)
>>> n, d = expr2.as_numer_denom()
>>> sympy.solve(d)
[0, -sqrt(3), sqrt(3), pi]
```

Obviously in this case SymPy does not list every multiple of pi as a solution; you'll have to process the list to generate solutions that lie in your desired domain.